# Broken pipe error with multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

In python2.7, multiprocessing.Queue throws a broken error when initialized from inside a function. I am providing a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing

def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

throws the below broken pipe error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
send(obj)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am unable to decipher why. It would certainly be strange that we cannot populate Queue objects from inside a function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT : please use [@Peter Svac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037027/3824723) answer, which is better. Usage of join_thread is ensuring the Queue does its job in a much much better fashion than the `time.sleep(0.1)` I proposed.**

What happens here is that when you call `main()`, it creates the `Queue`, put 10 objects in it and ends the function, garbage collecting all of its inside variables and objects, including the `Queue`.
BUT you get this error because you are still trying to send the last number in the `Queue`.

from the documentation [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) :

> "When a process first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is
> started which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe."

As the `put()` is made in another Thread, it is not blocking the execution of the script, and allows to ends the `main()` function before completing the Queue operations.

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing
import time
def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        q.put(i)
    time.sleep(0.1) # Just enough to let the Queue finish

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There should be a way to `join` the Queue or block execution until the object is put in the `Queue`, you should take a look in the documentation.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I am going to give another one stating that in python3 this does not happen.

Answer (score 27):

When You fire up Queue.put(), implicit thread is started to deliver data to a queue. Meanwhile, main application is finished and there is no ending station for the data (queue object is garbage-collected).

I would try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

def main():
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        q.put(i)
    q.close()
    q.join_thread()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`join_thread()` ensures, all data in the buffer has been flushed. `close()` must be called before `join_thread()`

Comment: Note that this has indeed been [fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80025) in Python 3.11 and was backported to [3.9.13](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92277) and [3.10.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92276) (based on PR merge date and py release schedules)

Answer (score -2):

With a delay using `time.sleep(0.1)` as suggested by @HarryPotFleur, this problem is solved. However, I tested the code with python3 and the broken pipe issue does not happen at all in python3. I think this was reported as a bug and later got fixed.

Comment: It's **not true**, that it don't happen in python3 at all.What is more
`time.sleep(0.1)` isn't solve! It's was just for understanding!

Comment: Using a sleep is not a solution, it's a hacky workaround. And this does happen in python3. https://bugs.python.org/issue35844