# multiprocessing.Queue : Broken pipe error

Tags: python, multithreading

Note1:
I want to use mutiprocessing.Queue in multiple process, When I found this issue occurs in single-process situation. So, the following code is use single process to simplify question.

There is a similar question : [Broken pipe error with multiprocessing.Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359528/broken-pipe-error-with-multiprocessing-queue).

The answer in that post proves that this issue is because the main thread exits before the queue thread finishes its job. The way he fixed it was by adding `sleep(0.1)` to his code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        print i
        q.put(i)
    time.sleep(0.1) # Just enough to let the Queue finish

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But, I think sleep is not a stable method for production code, so I tried to use `join` to do that. You can see my code below, but unfortunately, it does not work. Is there someone who knows how to do this without sleep?

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        q.put(i)
    # time.sleep(4)
    q.close()
    q.join_thread()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Using multiprocessing.Queue in just one process?

Comment: please see my edited question. in short, I want to use it with multi process, but when I raise this question, I choose to simplify question with minimal code.

Comment: You almost won't meet this issue in multi processes. Because you will have a consumer process which can block main process.

Comment: Yes, I try it with multi-process, it works fine. but I still curious why this happened in single process. The source of this question(code from my project) have issue, even with multiprocesing,  I will try to give another simplified code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first describe some details of `multiprocessing.Queue`.

> When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background **thread** later flushes the pickled data to an underlying **pipe**.

The pipe is created via `reader, writer = socket.socketpair()`.

`queue.close()` is designed for multi-processes and it does two things

1. close `reader` (important!)
2. send a `sentinel` value to `queue.buffer`, the background thread
   will exit if encounter such value

In single process case, the reason why `queue.close()` does not work is because **step 1**, if there still some data in `buffer`, the background thread will continue to write data to a already closed socket, which lead to `Broken pipe` error.

A simple example to demo the error

```
import socket

reader, writer = socket.socketpair()
writer.send("1")

# queue.close() will internally call reader.close()
reader.close()

# got a Broken pipe error
writer.send("2")
```

In multi-processes case, close `reader` in main process only decrement the reference count of the underlying socket(the main and child process share the socket), not really close (or shutdown) the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Program:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q.put(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 251, in _feed
    send_bytes(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 205, in send_bytes 
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 416, in _send_bytes 
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 373, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

A `BrokenPipeError` exception is raised when the queue thread of a `multiprocessing.Queue` still sends enqueued items to the write end of the queue pipe *after* the read end of the queue pipe has been [automatically closed during its garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) following the garbage collection of the queue (the write end of the queue pipe is not garbage collected because it is also referenced by the queue thread).

I think this is a bug so I have opened a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31913) on GitHub.

A workaround is make sure that no enqueued items are left for the queue thread to send when the queue is garbage collected, by dequeuing all enqueued items before:

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q.put(0)
    q.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```